# Is PSU voltage ripple something to worry about?

Tags: power-supply, computer-building, voltage

I'm currently putting together my first computer and I've had my eye on a Fractal Design Newton R3. From all of the reviews I've read this PSU comes out shining with the exception of voltage ripple on the 3.3V line (~50mV).

For the sake of keeping this open I'd like to know whether voltage ripple is a serious concern for any of the power lines. And if so, what is a tolerable level of Voltage ripple on each line?

Comment: @techie007 This question is about ripple (AC bleeding through to the DC), not output voltage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

50mV is the acceptable limit for ripple on all lines but the 12V line (per the ATX specification), so that would include the 3.3V line. Every device that draws power off the line has its own protection against ripple up to the permitted limit, so there's no reason it should cause a problem.

Comment: Please provide reference! I go across all pages of *microATX Motherboard Interface Specification v1.2* and *microATX Electrical Design Suggestions v1.1* and there are no any words about PSU noise level. Just saying about +/- 5% tolerance to voltage level.

Comment: It's in the [ATX specfication](http://www.formfactors.org/developer/specs/atx12v%20psdg2.01.pdf) see section 3.2.6.

Comment: Thanks! It on Intel *ATX12V Power Supply Design Guide* v2.01 2004 which I didn't read. Same requirement present in Intel *Power Supply Design Guide for Desktop Platform Form Factors* v1.2 2008. ATX specs spread among a lot of parts (( Thanks again!